What is the name of the XML file that generates the PDF invoice report and how can I know it?
I am trying to add a new column (Number of Members) to the PDF invoice and hide the tax column. When I generate the PDF file, no change happens. I want to know which XML file generates the invoice.
Here is my XML:
<odoo>
    <template id="report_invoice_inherit" inherit_id="account.report_invoice_document">
     
        <xpath expr="//table[@name='invoice_line_table']//thead//tr" position="inside">
            <th name="th_members" class="text-end"><span>Number of Members</span></th>
        </xpath>

      
        <xpath expr="//table[@name='invoice_line_table']//tbody//tr//td[@name='td_quantity']" position="after">
            <td name="td_members" class="text-end">
                <span t-field="line.num_members"/>
            </td>
        </xpath>

      
        <xpath expr="//table[@name='invoice_line_table']//thead//tr//th[@name='th_taxes']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="class">d-none</attribute>
        </xpath>
        <xpath expr="//table[@name='invoice_line_table']//tbody//tr//td[@name='td_taxes']" position="attributes">
            <attribute name="class">d-none</attribute>
        </xpath>
    </template>
</odoo>


<>(source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60622091/inherit-and-modify-the-account-report-invoice-document-table)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938070/odoo-11-qweb-report-xpath-tag-replace-not-replacing

Here is the file location:
account/views/report_invoice.xml,

